# TinyAuth: Authorization adapter "TinyAuth.Tiny" was not found

Tags: authorization, cakephp-3.0, acl

Im using CakePHP 3 along with TinyAuth plugin for authorization.

After installing TinyAuth in CakePHP 3.0 with Composer, and enabling it in AppController when I try to log in I get the following error:

> Authorization adapter "TinyAuth.Tiny" was not found

This is how I initalize it in AppController:

```
'authorize' => [
                    'TinyAuth.Tiny' => [
                        'roleColumn' => 'role_id',
                        'rolesTable' => 'Roles',
                        'multiRole' => true,
                        'pivotTable' => 'roles_users',
                        'superAdminRole' => null,
                        'authorizeByPrefix' => false,
                        'prefixes' => [],
                        'allowUser' => false,
                        'adminPrefix' => null,
                        'autoClearCache' => true
                    ]
```

And I load it in bootstrap.php like so:

```
Plugin::load('TinyAuth', []);
```

Answer (score 1):

in bootstrap.php try:

```
Plugin::load('TinyAuth');
```

or

```
Plugin::load('TinyAuth', ['autoload' => true]);
```

[Load plugins in cakephp 3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#loading-a-plugin)

Comment: `Plugin::load('TinyAuth', ['autoload' => true]);`

That was what i needed, thanks!